# Problem with fetching info in a state. Somebody could help me?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-state

I´m working with react js and fetching data in firebase, but i had a problem with data. My problem is in the variable "data". The data of the function "capturarPaginacion" is storing in a in the state "data" but I´m obtaining the initial value of this state. Curiosly, i´m changing the state (setState(list)) with an array "list" but when i use a console.log(list) to see what is happening in list, i recieve correctly the array with the data.

```
        const capturarPaginacion = async () => {
            let list = [];
            try {
                // Utilizamos collectionGroup() para obtener todos los documentos de "diary" en todas las solicitudes
                const subCollectionSnapshot = await getDocs(collectionGroup(db, "diary"));
                // Creamos un mapa para agrupar los datos de "diary" por su ID de solicitud
                const diaryDataMap = new Map();
                subCollectionSnapshot.forEach((subDoc) => {
                    const data = subDoc.data();
                    const solicitudId = data.idSolicitude;
                    if (!diaryDataMap.has(solicitudId)) {
                        diaryDataMap.set(solicitudId, []);
                    }
                    diaryDataMap.get(solicitudId).push(data);
                });

                // Obtenemos los datos de las solicitudes
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "solicitudes"));
                for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
                    const solicitudData = doc.data();
                    const solicitudId = doc.id;

                    // Obtenemos los datos de "diary" asociados a la solicitud actual
                    const datosAdicionalesData = diaryDataMap.get(solicitudId) || [];

                    // Combinamos los datos de la colección principal con los datos de la subcolección
                    const combinedUserData = { id: solicitudId, ...solicitudData, datosAdicionales: datosAdicionalesData };
                    list.push(combinedUserData);
                }

                // Sort the data by `notificationDateAndHour`
                list.sort((a, b) => {
                    const dateA = a.datosAdicionales.notificationDateAndHour;
                    const dateB = b.datosAdicionales.notificationDateAndHour;
                    return new Date(dateB) - new Date(dateA); // Sort in descending order
                })
                setData(list)
                console.log(list)
                console.log(data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
        capturarPaginacion()
    }, [])
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLSWj.png)[console.log(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTfsF.png)[code image with console.log(list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O0SZ.png)[console.log(list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouEBd.png)

I´d tried to put an await in the list.sort, but the result is the same in "data"... = []

Comment: I´m new in this. I put the code and the images are in the links

Comment: Thanks, but we'll still likely need a complete, runnable [mcve] to help.

Comment: How I could do this? Cause the code is extracting the data from a collection and subcollection from firebase.

Comment: Isolate the problem--if firebase is returning the data correctly, then you can just mock out that API call. If it's not returning the data correctly, then the React/JS code is probably irrelevant. The point of a minimal example is twofold: (1) only the parts you share are relevant to reproducing the problem; there are no unnecessary pieces of code and (2) the example is runnable so others can see what the problem is. Without this simple reproduction, it's unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: I know, and my problem it´s kinda weird cause as you said, i´m recieving the data from firebase correctly but my problem is that i can´t save this data in the state. I think that could be with the time that arriving the data, cause it´s taking the initial state instead of list value

Comment: Then it should be fairly simple to mock out that call, eliminate that from the question and provide a runnable snippet so others can assist you. Isolate the problem.